# In MYSQL max() is giving me some weird answer

Tags: php, mysql

I am using max() in my Mysql query.

```
$sql="SELECT max(`invoice_number`) 
      FROM `order_details` 
      WHERE `financial_year` = '$years' ";

$sql1= $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
print_r($sql1);

die();
```

The weird thing that is happening is upto 10 in database table, it shows the max value is 10 but the moment it is 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 it still shows 10.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: which contents has `$years`? post `var_dump($years)`

Comment: The value of $years is 1718. And it is same for all the rows in database.

Comment: what is the field type of 'invoice_number'

Comment: Yes @AzeezKallayi is right... the data type of the field must be integer to work with `MAX()` function. so check that

Comment: The field type of invoice_number is varchar.

Comment: post the table structure and some contents

Comment: @prakashtank [`MAX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) works with strings as well. And even as strings, `'11'` is still greater than `'10'`.

Comment: @AzeezKallayi thanks buddy you are right. I overlooked that bit.

Comment: @Shantanu cool buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the field `invoice_number` is a `varchar` you must do this to get your expected result:

```
  $sql="SELECT max( cast(`invoice_number` as unsigned) )
  FROM `order_details` 
  WHERE `financial_year` = '$years' ";
```

See also here for more informations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-row.html